# Total second derivative of function dependent on other functions

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

We have the functions $A, B, C$ where $B=B(A)$, $C=C(B,A)$ and we want to compute the total second derivative of $C$, $C_{dd}$.

The first total derivative $C_d$ is given by the following formula:

$$
C_d = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial C}{\partial X_i} \cdot {X_i}_d = \frac{\partial C}{\partial A} \cdot A_d + \frac{\partial C}{\partial B} \cdot B_d
$$
where the subscript $d$ indicates the total derivative.

Is there any general formula that gives the second order derivative $C_{dd}$ of a function with $n$ inputs?

Comment: The implied $B(x) = B(A(x))$ and $C(x) = C(B(x), A(x))$ are problematic because they use the same symbols $B$ and $C$ for different functions. Sometimes when meaning is clear enough this is an okay convenience, but here it will very likely cause confusion, if not wrong answers to the original intended question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=a(x), B=b(x),$ and  $C=c(A,B)$

Then we have $\hspace{13ex}\dfrac{\mathrm d C}{\mathrm d x}=\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial A}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d A}{\mathrm d x}+\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial B}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d B}{\mathrm d x}$

So the second derivative is: $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2 C}{\mathrm d x~^2}=\dfrac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm dx}\left[\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial A}\cdotp\dfrac{\mathrm d A}{\mathrm d x}\right]+\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm dx}\left[\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial B}\cdotp\dfrac{\mathrm d B}{\mathrm d x}\right]$

Now apply the **Product Rule**, then the **Chain Rule**, and clean up with a little algebra.

Then generalise.